# Regex on Term aggregations with phrase

Tags: elasticsearch

How can I aggregate a term filter based on the phrase? The field  auto is analyzed with shingle analyzer.The below query works fine with single keyword without whitespace when there is whitespace it fails. Any better way of doing it?

```
{
  "query" : {
    "prefix" : {
      "auto" : "Hello Wo*"
    }
  },
  "aggregations" : {
    "auto" : {
      "terms" : {
        "field" : "auto",
        "size" : 1000,
        "include" : "Hello Wo.*"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: So do I get it right you want an aggregation over the field auto but only include every bucket starting with "Hello Wo" ?

Comment: True, I need to filter with keywords starts with Hellow Wo

Comment: Did you check what buckets you get? (exclude the include part) Are all the buckets you get by this what you expect (Most likely every combination of 2 adjacent words)

Comment: If i exclude the include part i receive all the keywrods which is from the content.

Comment: Are they in the form you expect the analyzer to analyze this? For example if you put in "Hello World I am at StackOverflow" you should have the Buckets: ["Hello World", "World I", "I am", "am at", "at StackOverflow"]. Your above query should then only return "Hello World" bucket.

Comment: Not really this is what i am receiving  "buckets": [
            {
               "key": "am",
               "doc_count": 1
            },
            {
               "key": "at",
               "doc_count": 1
            },
          
            {
               "key": "stackoverflow",
               "doc_count": 1
            },
            {
               "key": "world",
               "doc_count": 1
            }
         ]

Comment: Than I think the problem is not your query but how your field is analyzed. Are you sure its shingle? Try GET ```urindex/_mapping``` and see what it says/post it in your question. 

Are you sure you want what you are asking for here? I don't get the usecase (which does not mean much though..)

Answer (score 0):

try the raw version of the field:

```
{
  "query" : {
   "prefix" : {
     "auto.raw" : "Hello Wo*"
    }
  },
 "aggregations" : {
  "auto" : {
    "terms" : {
      "field" : "auto.raw",
      "size" : 1000,
      "include" : "Hello Wo.*"
    }
  }
}}
```